# Declaring multiple variable oracle sql script

Tags: sql, oracle

Using oracle 11g 64bit and sqldeveloper 4.0. Trying to run the below sql script:

```
variable  v_sak_id NUMBER; 
variable  v_idNum varchar; 
exec :v_idNum := 'A1111200';
select sak_id into :v_sak_id from MemerId where idNum= :v_idNum;
```

Getting error message:

> Usage: VAR[IABLE] [  [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE])
>   | VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) | NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB
>   | NCLOB | REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
>
> anonymous block completed Error starting at line : 6 in command -
>   select sak_id into :v_sak_id from MemerId where idNum= :v_idNum Error
>   report - SQL Error: ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
>   01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Any help?

Comment: does this work: `where idNum='v_idNum';`

Answer (score 2):

1. When you declare a string variable, you have to specify the size of that variable.
2. Although as of now the `varchar` and `varchar2` are synonyms, please do not use `varchar` use `varchar2` datatatype. Oracle is planing to redefine `varchar` datatype as a separate datatype.
3. As it already has been told `select into` statement is used in Pl/SQL, so you should put your `select` statement in a `begin end` block or execute your `select` statement by using `exec` command, which, under the hood, wraps your select statement in `begin end` block:

Example(I assume that there was a typo and the table's name should be `memBerid`, but anyway. Left as it was.):

```
create table  memerid(
 sak_id number,
 idNum varchar2(123)
);

insert into MemerId(sak_id, idNum)
  values(1, 'A1111200');

commit;

variable  v_sak_id number; 
variable  v_idNum  varchar2(123); 

exec :v_idNum := 'A1111200';
exec select sak_id into :v_sak_id from MemerId  where idNum= :v_idNum;

print v_sak_id;
```

Result:

```
table MEMERID created.
1 rows inserted.
committed.
anonymous block completed
anonymous block completed

V_SAK_ID
-
1
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ... INTO ...` is PL/SQL syntax, not SQL. Since you're running in SQL Developer, you can just use `select sak_id from MemerId where idNum= :v_idNum;` and you will get prompted for the value of v_idNum. Additional executions with the bind variable will retain the previous value, or you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
variable  v_sak_id NUMBER; 
variable  v_idNum varchar; 
exec :v_idNum := 'A1111200';

begin
   select sak_id into :v_sak_id from MemerId where idNum= :v_idNum;
end;
```

That is, the `select ... into` construct/statement needs to be enclosed in a PL/SQL block which is achieved by embedding the statement within a `begin .. end`.

Comment: i want to avoid using pl/sql since i have lot of select that i need to print using sak_id

Comment: So then you need to ask more specifically and formulate what you want.